# The path template 'LibWorkspaces(company={key})' on the action 'GetLibWorkspaces' in controller 'LibWorkspaces' is not a valid OData path template

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

My controller code is:
[EnableQuery]
    public class LibWorkspacesController : ODataController
    {

```
   [ODataRoute("LibWorkspaces(company={key})")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLibWorkspaces([FromODataUri] string company) 
    {
        LibWorkspaces libWorkspaces = new LibWorkspaces();
        return Ok(libWorkspaces.getList(company).AsQueryable());
    }
```

There is a:  builder.EntitySet("LibWorkspaces"); in the webapiconfig

But I am getting the error "The path template 'LibWorkspaces(company={key})' on the action 'GetLibWorkspaces' in controller 'LibWorkspaces' is not a valid OData path template"

What do I need to do to return a generic list for a parameter?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

user14268:

1. For `[ODataRoute("LibWorkspaces(company={key})")]`, just make sure `company` is same as the key name (Case sensitive). Besides, the parameter name of `GetLibWorkspaces` should be same as the string in `{}`. Therefore, in your scenario, your action should have the following definition:

   public IHttpActionResult GetLibWorkspaces([FromODataUri] string **key**)
2. For single key scenario, you can omit the key name in the `ODataRoute` attribute. For example:

   [ODataRoute("LibWorkspaces({anyKeyName})")]

   public IHttpActionResult GetLibWorkspaces([FromODataUri] string anyKeyName)

   {
       ...
   }

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you I am one step closer So now I have:[ODataRoute("LibWorkspaces({key})")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetLibWorkspaces([FromODataUri] string key) 
         but calling it : http://localhost:1234/api/LibWorkspaces('ofer') shows the error :<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:1234/api/LibWorkspaces('ofer')'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'LibWorkspaces('ofer')'.
</MessageDetail>

Comment: Make sure the attribute routing is enabled. How do you call "MapODataServiceRoute"?